# register_rest_field update_callback don't work for $_FILES

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, rest-api

I try to insert a post with REST API who contain text and image in one api call.

My image is an acf field.

I register my field like that:

```php
register_rest_field( 'project', 'logo', array(
    'get_callback'       => 'get_field_logo',
    'update_callback'    => 'update_field_logo',
    )
);
register_rest_field( 'project', 'headline', array(
    'get_callback'       => 'get_field_headline',
    'update_callback'    => 'update_field_headline',
    )
);
```

I send my request via Postman
[image: postman]

`update_field_headline` is correctly call, but `update_field_logo` is never call.

I try to debug `wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-controller.php`

on line 421 is see:

```php
// Don't run the update callbacks if the data wasn't passed in the request.
if ( ! isset( $request[ $field_name ] ) ) {
    continue;
}
```

I think `update_field_logo` is never call because "logo" is not set inside $_POST variable but inside $_FILES variable. So in line 421 the field is skipped.

If I modifiy the core file on line 421 like below everythings work well

```php
if ( ! isset( $request[ $field_name ] ) && ! isset($_FILES[ $field_name ] ) {
    continue;
}
```

But modify WordPress Core file is not a solution...

Any idea how can I allow files to be trigger on update_callback ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but i'm sure there is a better way.

I add an action on `rest_insert_<post_type>` hook

```php
add_action( 'rest_insert_project', 'prefix_update_files_field', 10 , 3 );

function prefix_update_files_field($post, $request, $true){
    global $wp_rest_additional_fields;
    $my_post_type = 'project';
    $additional_fields = $wp_rest_additional_fields[$my_post_type];
    foreach ( $additional_fields as $field_name => $field_options ) {

        if ( ! $field_options['update_callback'] ) {
            continue;
        }
        // Don't run the update callbacks if the data wasn't passed in the request.
        if ( !  isset($_FILES[ $field_name ] )  ) {
            continue;
        }

        $result = call_user_func( $field_options['update_callback'], $_FILES[ $field_name ], $post, $field_name, $request, $my_post_type );

        if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```